# Solve differential equation by separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Using separation of variables find solutions to the equation $3u_{xy}=u$. My attempt:

$u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y) \Rightarrow u_{xy}=X'(x)Y'(y) \Rightarrow 3X'Y'=XY$

From what I've seen and read, it's necessary get an expression like
$\frac{A'}{A}=\frac{B'}{B}$, but in this case I got $\frac{3X'}{X}=\frac{Y}{Y'}$

Can somebody help me? I haven't had a course in partial differential equations yet, this question came out in my current course in Fourier analysis. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this falls under the purview of an expression "like" $\frac{A'}{A} = \frac{B'}{B}.$ Do you know the next step?

Comment: Even if I get \frac{Y}{Y'} instead of \frac{Y'}{Y}? No, I really don't know it

Comment: @StephenDonovan: comment removed.

Comment: The technique will work with $f(X(x),X'(x))=g(Y(y),Y'(y))$, provided the equation is linear (so that you can later superpose the solutions).

Answer (score 1):

It is important not to drop the variables $x$ and $y$. What you have here is $\frac {3X'(x)} {X(x)}=\frac {Y(y)} {Y'(y)}$. LHS depends only on $X$ and RHS only on $y$. This implies that both sides are  actually independent of $x$ and $y$. So there is a constant $C$ such that $\frac {3X'(x)} {X(x)}=C=\frac {Y(y)} {Y'(y)}$. Now you get $3X'(x)=CX(x)$ and $Y'(y)=\frac 1 C Y(y)$. I will let you solve these two ODE's.

Comment: What guarantees the existence of such a constant?

Comment: To see why it must be constant, consider differentiating that equation with respect to either variable.

Comment: @rreevv97 One side is independent of $y$ and the other side is independent of $x$. And these two sides are equal. So neither side can depened on $x$ or $y$.

Comment: If you hold $x$ constant, then you see that $3X'(x)/X(x)$ does not vary with $y$, and therefore $Y(y)/Y'(y)$ must be a equal to a constant. The reverse argument shows that $3X'(x)/X(x)$ does not vary with $x$. So there is a constant $\lambda$ such that $3X'(x)/X(x)=\lambda=Y(y)/Y'(y)$, and that decouples into two separate equations: $3X'(x)/X(x)=\lambda$ and $Y(y)/Y'(y)=\lambda$. All that assumes a solution of the form $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$.